# How to close a jgrowl manually

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, jgrowl

All,

How to close and open a jgrowl manually

```
 jQuery("div.jGrowl").trigger("jGrowl.close");
```

The above code doesnt seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me

```
$("div.jGrowl").jGrowl("close");
```

Comment: This syntax apparently doesn't work anymore. All it did for me was pop another jGrowl with a message of "close"

Answer (score 2):

Three options:

```
$('div.jGrowl').find('div.jGrowl-notification').children().parent().remove();

$('div.jGrowl').find('div.jGrowl-notification').trigger('jGrowl.close');

$('div.jGrowl').find('.jGrowl-close').trigger('jGrowl.close');
```

Any of them close all notifications. I'm not sure how to close an individual notification, though.

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me, closing the last notification:

```
$('div.jGrowl-close').triggerHandler('click');
```

Edit: Improved efficiency by replacing trigger with triggerHandler. See http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue because I was adding a set of buttons into the growl notification.  One was used to accept the notification and the other was used to ignore the notification.  The approach I took was to add an `afterOpen` callback and then add a `click` handler with the reference to the original close element:

```
afterOpen: function(e,m,o){
    $(e).find("#acceptInvitation").click(function() {
        alert( "Invite Accepted" );
    });
    $(e).find("#declineInvitation").click(function() {
        $(e).children("div.jGrowl-close").trigger('click');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The namespace comes after the event ..

so it should be

```
jQuery("div.jGrowl").trigger("close.jGrowl");
```

***update after comment***
The syntax mentioned in their blog *could* be a typo .. (did you try it out to see if it works ?)

Other than that, a support request at jquery plugins page dated feb 2009 may contain some more insight .. have a look ..

Comment: @Gaby:
> [According](http://www.stanlemon.netindex.jgrowl.html) to this it is as i said

Comment: weird .. perhaps it is a typo ... did you try it out ?

Answer (score 1):

The best method is

```
$(".jGrowl-notification:last-child").remove();
```

When jGrowl create a notification it use to create two jGrowl-notification DIVs where one is empty. So when ever you create a notification the last is the latest notification. So you need to close the last DIV with jGrowl-notification class.

When ever you wanted to open only single note use the below code, which will remove the previous note and create a new one

```
$(".jGrowl-notification:last-child").remove();

$.jGrowl("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(".jGrowl-notification:last-child").jGrowl('close');`

or

`$(".jGrowl-notification:last-child").trigger('jGrowl.close')`

Are the best ways to close a notification as all of the callbacks will be triggered accordingly.

Removing the mode bypasses the callbacks, which is less then ideal. Also note that to close a specific notification you will want to use the selector noted above.

The `$.fn.jGrowl()` method call is designed to parallel jQuery.UI's widget approach and has become fairly common place and I will most likely maintain this in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to close individual notifications:

```
testGrowl = function() {
 var ao, close;
 close = function(e) {
  console.log('close');
  return $(e).find('.jGrowl-close').trigger('click');
 };
 ao = function(e) {
   return setTimeout(function() {
   return close(e);
  }, 1500);
 };
 return $.jGrowl("Hello world!", {
   sticky: true,
   afterOpen: ao
  });
 };
setTimeout(testGrowl, 100);
setTimeout(testGrowl, 1000);
```

[CoffeeScript and dialog here](http://knoopgroup.com/blog/manually-closing-jgrowl-notifications/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution for opening and closing individual messages that uses jGrowl's grouping feature:

```
var nextGroupID = 1;

var addMessage = function(message)
{
    var groupID = nextGroupID++;
    $.jGrowl(message, { sticky: true, group: "group-" + groupID });
    return groupID;
};

var removeMessage = function(groupID)
{
    $("div.jGrowl-notification.group-" + groupID).trigger("jGrowl.close");
}

// Example usage
addMessage("The first test message");
var testID = addMessage("The second test message");

setTimeout(function() {removeMessage(testID);}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the click function and catch the event to close the current notification.
For example:

```
$.jGrowl('Hi, It's a clickable close notification', {
      click: function(e, m, o) {
        $(e).jGrowl("close");
      }
    });
```

Here **e** refers to event, **m** for the message and **o** refers to the options.

Check [this](https://github.com/stanlemon/jGrowl) for more details.

**NOTE**: Use the latest jgrowl lib 1.3 onward.

Comment: You just need to run your snippet to see the error.

Comment: Hi Armel, Sorry for convinience. It's just an example. Use this example(https://github.com/stanlemon/jGrowl/tree/master/examples) with my snippet. Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#jGrowl').find('.jGrowl-close').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Please add description to yuor answer